# How containers run on an AWS EC2 virtualization exactly?

Tags: amazon-ec2, containers, runtime, hypervisor

As they say, containers do not run on the Hypervisor layer so what happens when we run Container on an AWS EC2 instance? Since EC2 itself is running on a hypervisor layer managed by AWS.

Can someone please help me understand this better?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to provide more information to back up your question.  In the gaps, there are a lot of interpretations for what you are asking, so in a quick return to the basics:

1. A Hypervisor presents to an Operating System what looks like an independent machine that it can execute on.   It might have some weird drivers (aka virtio) but it is just a machine.
2. A Container presents to a Program what looks like an independent Operating System.  It might have some weird IP addresses (127.x.y.z), and stuff, but it looks like it has its own OS.

Note that with [2], the Program can start a whole bunch of other Programs, so as far as it is concerned, it has an entire OS to itself.  In reality it is sharing its machine with other Containers, each of which think they have their own machine, and some Root machine which is hosting the Containers.

Containers can host other Containers (well, at least in theory).

Hypervisors can host other Hypervisors (in practise, but your mileage might vary).

So, a Container is an Operating System Instance, running within an Operating System, which might be running within a Virtual Machine on a Hypervisor which is running several Virtual Machines each of which might be running Operating systems which are hosting multiple Containers.

If it strikes you that this is why we can’t have nice things, yes, you are right.

Comment: Thank you so much. This really helps to put the underlying public cloud hardware to container stake into perspective.